# SQL - Match value if exists; else match NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table:

| country | state | county | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'us' | 'ny' | 'steuben' | **NULL** |
| 'us' | 'ny' | 'steuben' | 'city a' |
| 'us' | 'ny' | 'steuben' | 'city b' |
| 'us' | 'ny' | **NULL** | **NULL** |
| 'us' | **NULL** | **NULL** | **NULL** |
| **NULL** | **NULL** | **NULL** | **NULL** |

The goal is to have some sort of query where "country, state, county, and city" are always supplied, but what is provided may not exist in the table. If a supplied attribute isn't found, I would like the relevant 'NULL' value from the column.

*Example:*
User provides "us, ny, steuben, city b" --> Row #3

*Example:*
User provides "us, ny, steuben, city c" --> Row #1 because 'city c' is unknown

*Example:*
User provides "us, ny, hamilton, city a" --> Row #4 because 'hamilton' is unknown

The original thought was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [location] 
WHERE 
   (country = @country OR country IS NULL) AND
   ([state] = @state OR [state] IS NULL) AND
   (county = @county OR county IS NULL) AND
   (city = @city OR city IS NULL)
```

However, this will return the NULL rows indiscriminately. What I'm really looking for is some sort of logic like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [location] 
WHERE 
   (country = @country IF EXISTS OR country IS NULL) AND
   ([state] = @state IF EXISTS OR [state] IS NULL) AND
   (county = @county IF EXISTS OR county IS NULL) AND
   (city = @city IF EXISTS OR city IS NULL)
```

Does anyone have a potential solution?

Note: If the answer varies with databases, I'm interested in MS-SQL.

Comment: Your database is denormalized. Is there a reason you can't normalize your design? That way the query will be easier to write because you can specify the user's data as a series of `JOIN` constraints.

Comment: No, I suppose there's not. It's only 'denormalized' by accident  (I am VERY new to SQL). I'm not exactly sure what you mean by normalizing. Is there a resource you could point me to that would demonstrate what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filtering and `order by`:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
where (t.country = @country or t.country is null) and
      (t.state = @state or t.state is null) and
      (t.county = @county or t.county is null) and
      (t.city = @city or t.city is city)
order by ( (case when t.country = @country then 1 else 0 end) +
           (case when t.state = @state then 1 else 0 end) +
           (case when t.county = @county then 1 else 0 end) +
           (case when t.city = @city then 1 else 0 end)
         ) desc;
```

The key is to order by the number of full matches descending.